# Trying to webharvest images of fractals

Tags: images, search, url, google-search, save-as

I am trying to webharvest all of the images from this google images URL for a project:

`https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sa=G&tbs=simg:CAESgwIagAILEKjU2AQaAggKDAsQsIynCBqbAQo6CAISFPwImhWTCNgL-wiXDJIIhwiACdQLGiD-9XWrKvLUZ8Vlra3ZQmb2jN-jRi0c9zS1DY69bz2WHwpdCAMSJ9UThAPqE9YTpgifA6AD4hNf6ROnKOwhsTS2NJg-xD2WPsY2rzW-Nhow0bkXh0sZAbenb-bUloIJ2pAmLO22IArnzhccTzdVISQF7WgzupheDr4bUm8yu8qaDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIEO-R9uwwLEJ3twQkaNAoHCgVzaGFwZQoJCgdkaWFncmFtCgYKBGFyZWEKCgoIY2xpcCBhcnQKCgoIdHJpYW5nbGUM&q=sierpinski+triangle&tbm=isch&ei=B7-5VJa-FIOcNoSXgPgG&ved=0CCwQsw4&biw=1164&bih=601`

Specifically I am trying to harvest around 630 images of the simplest forms of fractals.

Exactly how would I go about doing this? I am familiar with [webharvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/) but I am unable to get such a specific search to work for harvesting images. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

I figured out how to webharvest...but now I think 190000 images instead of 630 for it to be a valid test with the software I am using...https://github.com/wnd-charm/wnd-charm

Any ideas for easiest way to harvest that many images (fractals) off of the interwebs?

Comment: Googled a bit, tried the first software I found: http://www.exisoftware.com/picture_finder/

PRetty nifty and works like a charm :) It's not free though, but you can evaluate it for twenty days.

Comment: @SadBunny you might be better at googling thane me - what software?

Comment: @SadBunny the new problem is i need roughly 190000 images of grayscale fractals...i know how to manipulate a google search to get them...but that is a lot...and it seems like webharvest can only do 20 at a time.

Comment: Sorry, messed up that first comment, posted it before I pasted the link. Updated it now.

Comment: @SadBunny - this looks great - ill let you/all the nerds know how it goes :)

Comment: @SadBunny - you were def on the right track..i am getting this networking error - have tried a few things but not sure what is wrong...i have tried on kali and ubuntu with wine (i dont have windows) - Your project finished but zero target files were saved. All starting addresses in the project returned the same HTTP error code: 404. Please go to the project options and make sure you entered correct starting addresses.

Comment: Well... The program worked for me on Windows 8.1 and saved about 5000 fractal images in the few seconds I allowed it to run. I did't enter any settings menu and changed nothing, just searched for "fractal" and let it go. I have no idea what goes wrong in wine or what to try under Linux :) Good luck though.

Comment: @SadBunny thanks - i actually got it working on Ubuntu...so I will do just that...thank you so much! please provide an answer to this question with a link to the program you showed me!

Comment: @SadBunny - you should put in you answer that it works with Wine! that was extremely helpful to me

Comment: Thanks for your thanks; glad to hear it works for you. But I'd rather not post an actual answer containing a link to some program I found - let them do their own marketing. You could always answer your own question :)

Comment: @SadBunny - haha - hey man....ur the genius so whatever works for you :)